# MKMapView freezes on User Interaction

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview

I have an application where I show a small map with one annotation, the map is in a objectDetailScreen that I created, this screen is updated whenever a new object is set, also showing a new map. The map as a annotation for the object.

Whenever I try to move the view, tap the annotations pin or zoom, the map freezes for a while and I have no clue why it does that. The app is iPad only (iPad 2, iOS 4.3.5).  Here is the code that sets the map:

```
- (void) setObject:(AchmeaObject *)_object
{

    if(kaart != nil)
    {
        [kaart removeFromSuperview];
        kaart = nil;
    }

    kaart = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(340, 380, 400,300)];
    [kaart setDelegate: self];
    [kaart setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = [_object.latitude doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [_object.longitude doubleValue];

    double miles = 2;
    double scalingFactor = ABS( cos(2 * M_PI * coordinate.latitude /360.0) );

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0;
    span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor*69.0);

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = coordinate;

    [kaart setRegion: region animated:YES];


    ObjectAnnotation  *sa = [[ObjectAnnotation alloc] initWithName: _object.plaats Address: _object.adres Coordinate:coordinate];

    NSArray *anotations = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sa];        

    [kaart addAnnotations:anotations];

    [self.view addSubview:kaart];

}
```

I have no idea why it happens, but when it first shows it takes a few seconds to respond to any user interaction, and after every interaction it needs at least a few more seconds, until after a few times freezing completely.

ObjectAnnotation.m

```
#import "ObjectAnnotation.h"


@implementation ObjectAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

- (id) initWithName: (NSString *) _name Address: (NSString *) _address Coordinate: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) _coord{
    self = [super init];
    name = [_name retain];
    address = [_address retain];
    _coordinate = _coord;
    return self;
}


- (NSString *)title {
    return name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return address;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [name release];
    name = nil;
    [address release];
    address = nil;    
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is related to re-adding new map views. Add a map view in the xib or very early in the view controller's life cycle and keep it hidden, and then show it and update its position (with `setRegion:animated:`). Creating a new map view each time is both expensive and unnecessary; if you're doing it because you want to get rid of some state (annotations, the map's region), learn how to reset that state in the existing map view instead.

It could also be related to your ObjectAnnotation, to which you do not provide the source code.

Comment: It already happens for the first map, so i should not be the adding and removing, although you make a good point. Adding the ObjectAnnotation now, but it is nothing special.

Comment: Not sure why, in that case. Run it under Instruments, under Time Profiler and see what's taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem. After profiling, I find out tint property could be causing the map refresh delay. So I set default tint at storyboard and problem disappeared.

Comment: This IS an answer to the question.  No reason to delete it.